# Procmail recipe with capturing group

Tags: procmail

Trying to direct email based on a regex match.

I know I can do this:

```
echo | mail -s test1 me-route2
```

with this recipe:

```
* ^To:.*me-route2\@
:0:
/home/me/folder-route2/afile
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
* ^To:.*me-(route\d)\@
:0:
/home/me/folder-$MATCH/afile
```

but I am getting:

```
procmail: Lock failure on "/home/me/folder-/afile.lock"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the prologue line and the condition in the wrong order.  But in addition, Procmail does not recognize the Perlism `\d`.  (See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856054/bash-easy-way-to-pass-a-raw-string-to-grep/11857890#11857890) for a bit of regex history and arcana.) Try this instead:

```
:0:
* ^To:.*me-\/route[0-9]
/home/me/folder-$MATCH/afile
```

or, if you really want to verify that the matching expression is immediately followed by an @ sign,

```
:0:
* ^To:.*me-\/route[0-9]@
* MATCH ?? ^\/route[0-9]
/home/me/folder-$MATCH/afile
```

From the input `To: reallynotme-route2@example.com`, the first condition captures `route2@` and the second condition matches up through `route2` in order to drop the trailing `@` from `MATCH`.

My suspicion is that no lock file is necessary, so the second colon should be removed, but this depends on what `afile` is.  If it's a regular Berkely mbox file, you should definitely use locking.  If it's a Maildir folder, you should not.

You might also want to look into replacing `^To:.*me` with `^TO_me` -- it will match on `Cc:` and other pertinent headers as well as a literal `To:` header, and avoid matching on `reallynotme`.

Answer (score 0):

Procmail doesn't use capture groups like normal regular expressions, at least for MATCH. From the man page:

> This variable is assigned to by  procmail  whenever  it  is  told  to
>   extract  text from a matching regular expression.  It will contain all
>   text matching  the  regular  expression  past the `/' token.

So the following should work (untested):

```
* ^To:.*me-\/route\d
```

`MATCH` will then contain whatever matched the regex after the `\/`, so "route\d".

Sadly this will do possibly unexpected things with an address like `me-route2-ab@example.com`, with `MATCH` being "route2".  But that may be acceptable to you.

Comment: Hmm.  Did not work (same behavior as before).  I think what I'll do is pipe to a program and separate it out there.  Thanks, anyway, Craig.

Comment: That's because `\d` only matches a literal character `d` in Procmail regex.